# Laravel and Android post parameter

Tags: android, laravel, post, request

This is the way I send POST parameter

```
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = newJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, FashionClient.UPLOAD_URL,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                Log.d("Send Text","JSON===="+jsonObject.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("Error","Error===="+volleyError.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("message", message);
            return params;
        }
    };
   ..............
    params.put("message", message);
```

And in Laravel

```
$message = Input::get('message');
```

But I can't receive a message. $message is NULL.
Please give me your opinion.
Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("message", message);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, FashionClient.UPLOAD_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //
                Log.e("TAG", "OK: " + response);
            }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
            Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + error);
        }
    });
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thank you so much

Comment: anh biết rành về laravel không. cho em bái sư với